# Fixed viewport height in Android

Tags: android, html, web-applications, height, viewport

I have an Android web app which can only be used in landscape.

When I set viewport width to a number everything works as expected. But for my purposes, I would like to use a fixed pixel height:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=500" />
```

Whatever I try, the height gets totally ignored. I've searched for hours and didn't find a solution to my problem.

For testing I created a simple html file with a div box, having height 500 and width 500. I expected the div to fill the whole device screen in height, but it doesn't.

Ideas? :-o

Comment: i ran into the same problem, digged a little deeper, even tried to workaround, but i'm still not happy nor do i have a solution. looks like a browser bug to me (although i could only test with safari on an ipad). did you find a solution meanwhile? heres my description, wich provides some more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376325/how-to-get-orientationportrait-mode-with-meta-viewport-with-a-fixed-height

Comment: No, I did not find a solution yet. I also tried javascript but it was no good option at all because when it failed the page looked horrible. And yes, it failed quite often...